# Distance in km between coordinates, Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, extents

I have coordinates for a bounding box:

```
1: [-109.41397027896355,22.86994450876419]
2: [-109.41397027896355,28.00000232204317]
3: [-115.75044209344128,28.00000232204317]
4: [-115.75044209344128,22.86994450876419]
```

And I want to find the distance between coordinates in order to get the height and width of the bounding box in kilometers. Are there any specific functions that do this in Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the distance between two `ee.Geometry` instances:

```
var coords = [
  [-109.41397027896355, 22.86994450876419],
  [-109.41397027896355, 28.00000232204317],
  [-115.75044209344128, 28.00000232204317],
  [-115.75044209344128, 22.86994450876419]
]

var width = distanceBetween(coords[0], coords[3])
var height = distanceBetween(coords[0], coords[1])

print(width, height)

function distanceBetween(coord1, coord2) {
  return ee.Geometry.Point(coord1).distance(
    ee.Geometry.Point(coord2)
  )
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/da282c29504c10570984d962bd4478ed